# write category name with model after laravel post post registration

Tags: laravel

I have 2 tables and my 1st table is Category 2 My Table is Posts, While I have a category, When I want to save a post, it is added as "category_id" in the post. but, what I want to do is $post->save(); after saying return response()->json([ 'data' =>$post]); I return. but what I want is to return the name of the category instead of the category_id.

While recording, I want to know the name of the post category recorded between the two models.

The content of my category and page models is what I need to write in the empty model

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'title' => 'required|max:255',
            'image' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:8192',
            'language' => 'required'
        ]);
$page = new Page;
$page->title = $request->title;
                $page->slug = $request->slug;
                $page->content = $request->contents;
                $page->category_id = $request->cat_id;
                $page->language = $request->language;
$page->save();
return response()->json([
                    'data' => $page,
                    'success' => 'File uploaded successfully.']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Laravel` can automatically serialize models, so ensure you have a relationship, load it into the model and it will be added to your `JSON` response automatically.

```
class Page extends Model {
   public function category()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
   }
}
```

Using `->load()` to lazy load the relationship, if similar has to be done in a query use `->with()` which is the eager loading approach.

```
...

$page->save();
$page->load('category');

return response()->json([
    'data' => $page,
    'success' => 'File uploaded successfully.',
]);
```

This will add the category as a relationship, but this is the best practice instead of adding the name in a more hard coded way.

Also one of the down sides of filling relationship ids as a property or with `fill()`. Is that it circumvented `Laravels` relationship logic, if you instead save the category relationship on the relationship function. It will have loaded the category and work, in the same manner as above.

```
$page->title = $request->title;
$page->slug = $request->slug;
$page->content = $request->contents;
$page->language = $request->language;

$page->category()->associate(Category::find($request->cat_id));

$page->save();
```